# Running a Flutter App in WSL shows a UI problem

Tags: linux, flutter, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have a problem here, and don't know if it's **wsl** bug (I don't think so) or it is a flutter bug in linux desktop development.

as the image shows I've created new counter app using vscode in **wsl**.

[image]

when app runs in debug mode or after building it it show the same problem.

although every other gui app works fine like nautilus and gedit and gnome-tweaks as well.

**some infos**

wsl --update

````
Checking for updates...
No updates are available.
Kernel version: 5.10.43```
````

flutter doctor -v (from wsl)

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 2.6.0-5.2.pre, on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 5.10.43.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2, locale C.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 2.6.0-5.2.pre at /home/abdurrahman/.flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 400608f101 (18 hours ago), 2021-09-15 15:50:26 -0700
    • Engine revision 1d521d89d8
    • Dart version 2.15.0 (build 2.15.0-82.2.beta)

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1
    • cmake version 3.16.3
    • ninja version 1.10.0
    • pkg-config version 0.29.1

[✗] Flutter IDE Support (No supported IDEs installed)
    • IntelliJ - https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/
    • Android Studio - https://developer.android.com/studio/
    • VS Code - https://code.visualstudio.com/

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Linux (desktop) • linux • linux-x64 • Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 5.10.43.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

host windows build

```
Version: 21H2
OS build: 22000.184
```

Comment: you dont install any editor as per your `flutter doctor` like `Flutter IDE Support (No supported IDEs installed)` so Install any one IDE in given list

Comment: Reported at https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/issues/569